# Can we create a lightning quick action through metadata api?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, lightning-quickaction

Is there a way to create a lightning-quick action using metadata API?

I want to create and add lightning-quick actions to layouts of certain sObjects, and those lightning-quick actions will launch lightning components, but I want to do it via API and Apex class code.

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. You can use 'deploy' method.

Optionally you can use sfdx cli for it.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use it from Apex, the easiest way is to use Metadata Connector if you want more options - github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi. Salesforce also provides limited Metadata API, it's mainly used to deploy Custom Metadata, but you can also use it to deploy Layouts https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_intro .

here is also a link to Metadata API reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based.htm

Comment: Are any support links available for 'deploy' method?

Comment: if you want to use it from Apex, the easiest way is to use Metadata Connector if you want more options - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi.
Salesforce also provides limited Metadata API, it's mainly used to deploy Custom Metadata, but you can also use it to deploy Layouts
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_intro

Comment: here is also a link to Metadata API reference https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based.htm

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to add any points of clarification. That is not what comments are for.

Comment: sure) thanks Adrian

Comment: @ytiq Saw this when checking out the new other answer given today. You told Adrian you would, but you never edited your answer to include the important information that you added in the comments. Please make that edit so that a future reader does not have to scour the comments in order to try find the real answer - the answer should be in, well, the answer post. :)

Comment: sure, sorry. Do it right now)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create an Quick Action on a sObject from Apex Class. You have to use Apex Metadata API for that purpose. Follow the blog below to get your answer, but before that, make sure you have correctly integrate your Endpoint URL which is your own org's URL into your org's Setup>Security>Remote Site Setting. If you don't add this URL, then it will throw missing Endpoint Error.

https://hicglobalsolutions.com/blog/create-a-dynamic-detail-page-button-for-any-sobject-using-meta-data/

If you have any problem in understanding what's the code, then as I did, go through the Apex Metadata API trailhead,

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api

Please ask for follow-up questions, if any!

Thanks!